# Only user show his data rules firebase database

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sketchware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hKWr.jpg)

So what do I keep the rules of firebase database

```
​{ "rules": { ".read": "auth != true", ".write": "auth != true" } }
```

​When I keep these rules, my application gets an error in addition to the image above

So what do I do if this error occurs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to only show the users document to the user that it belongs to you will need to have a reference to the user ID in said document for example:

```
-Users
    --jfkdsfsadfasfsda(users ID)
        ---userID: jfkdsfsadfasfsda
        ---username: Mike Oxlong
    --gfhfdghfdfgdhfdgfd
        ---userID: gfhfdghfdfgdhfdgfd
        ---username: Tess Tickle
```

and your rules would look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {


 match /users/{userID} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userID;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
 }
```

this will allow tess to read mikes user data but not edit or delete it however allowing tess to edit her own data. also it only allows registered users to create data.

https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw - this video is super helpful